# YOLO Training error with shape for my own dataset, Can someone help to understand this and help to solve the issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, yolo

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1,5) into shape (1,8)
```

Comment: Add your code also

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this error is occurring due to incompatibility between the shapes while broadcasting. There are some broadcasting rules that are followed when performing certain operations on `NumPy` arrays. You can read more about these rules [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/broadcasting-with-numpy-arrays/).